# Request hangs after RefreshToken expires JsonHttpClient ServiceStack

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack JsonHttpClient client (5.9.0) in my Xamarin.Forms mobile app.

Client is set like this:

```
client = new JsonHttpClient(App.BaseEndpoint)
{
   RefreshToken = RefreshToken,
};

var httpClient = client.GetHttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, timeout, 0);
```

Refreshing of Bearer token works perfect, but after Refresh Token expires request just hangs with no response and without any exception.

here is request example:

```
public async Task GetAsync(string uri)
{
   try
   {
      var response = await client.GetAsync<string>(uri);
   }
   catch (RefreshTokenException ex)
   {
      throw new SessionExpiredException(AppResources.Error_SessionExpired);
   }
 }
```

If I use JsonServiceClient instead - after expiration of RefreshToken I'm getting RefreshTokenException as expected

Maybe someone have some fix or workaround for this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten the `JsonHttpClient` manual Task continuations to use async/await in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/07a7874717e90104dfddc2a0b0ae0320ee3723ce) which should use a better tested code path in Xamarin.

This change is available from the latest ServiceStack v5.9.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

If it's still an issue you can try configuring `JsonHttpClient` to use the [Xamarin's native HttpClient implementations](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#xamarin-native-httpclient) for iOS using `NSUrlSessionHandler` and for Android using `AndroidClientHandler`.

Comment: Thank you  for quick response. Updating packages to v5.9.1 resolved the problem.

Comment: @Gn0me great happy to hear it :)