# ServiceStack translates HttpError.Unauthorized from backend into ArgumentNullException on client ("Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'RefreshToken')")

Tags: asp.net-core, xamarin, servicestack

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application which serves as API to mobile client written written Xamarin Forms.
An API has a TryAuthenticate method which expects userName and password to perform authentication. If credentials are incorrect, it throws `HttpError.Unauthorized(validationResult.Message)` exception.

On mobile client though for some reason it is being translated into `ArgumentNullException` with error message: "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'RefreshToken')".

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Client version: ServiceStack.Client 5.9.0.
Client classes that are used:

1. JsonServiceClient
2. JsonHttpClient

Both have the same behavior.

What is even more wild, is that when calling authentication endpoint with Postman, providing invalid credentials, it return correct (expected) response:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Would really appreciate any answer or suggestion, as working with ServiceStack gets only more difficult and unpredictable over time.

Comment: This call is the result of the Service Client trying to [Automatically refresh JWT Access Tokens](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#automatically-refreshing-access-tokens) which occurs after it receives the 401 error. Can you also try upgrading to the [latest v5.9.2 client which works better in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62527773/85785). Can you update your question to include the Server AuthFeature registration + the client code so I can check if this is expected behavior or not.